# How do I join a List View Web Part to the List View Web Part for the Tasks associated with that list?

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, dataviewwebpart

In SharePoint Designer 2010, I am trying to show three list view web parts on a page.  The three views are of a list (for example, Key Requests), the workflow items associated with that list and then the tasks associated with that list.  I want to be able to click on a item in the list and it refreshes the workflow and task list view web parts.  I am able to connect the workflow items to the list by joining the list item ID to the Primary Item ID field on the workflow list (under Managing Connections).  But connecting the list item to the task items seems a little more difficult.  Does anyone know how to do this?